# CodeIgniter with Twitter Bootstrap is not working in IE-8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

Am using Twitter bootstrap2.3.2 with CodeIgniter. Its working fine in all browsers except IE-8 and below. I have tried repond.js and css3-mediaqueries.js. But no result. Can any one guide me how to call that js files.So that it may be helpful for us.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have following in your HTML?

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML5 shim required by bootstrap which IE8 does not have.

Note that respond.js is required for enabling media queries on IE8. If you are not doing responsive layout, you probably don't need it (except on 3.0 where mobile layout is new default).

**Things to watch out:**

1. Make sure you are not trieng to view HTML page locally using file:// (i.e. without localhost).
2. Another thing to make sure is if you are using non-CDN URLs above then those paths are correct. You can check this by looking at Console in Chrome dev tools and see if you have any 404 GETs.
3. above scripts needs to be before boostrap.js. [See here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for full HTML example.

Comment: Am tried with scripts which you given above, but it's not working, I don't know where I am missed.